# How to calculate the entropy change in an adiabatic process?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, adiabatic

A 2 cm long, 10 mm diameter and 1.5 kW electric heater is used to heat 30 kg water in an insulated container.The initial and final temperatures of the water are 25 C and 90 C respectively. Calculate the time required to make hot water, the entropy generation during the process.

- In this question is it alright to assume this is an adiabatic process because it is an insulated system?
   Here i used dQ=mC(dT) to calculate the time.
   but I couldn't find a way to calculate the entropy change.
- How can we calculate the entropy generation of the system?

Comment: I am new user here too, but general policy here seems to not encourage direct homework questions. Try to ask what concept you don't understand.

Comment: Do you know how to determine the change in entropy of 30 kg of liquid water which in initial thermodynamic equilibrium state A is at 25 C and in final thermodynamic equilibrium state B is at 90 C?

Comment: I'm a new user here too.Please forgive for the mistake.But in order to understand the fundamental correctly I've given this question.And I assure you that this not a homework question, but a question I've faced while going through a thermodynamic related book.

Comment: @ChesterMiller : No.That is the thing I don't know.

Comment: Do you know the general equation for calculating the change in entropy between two thermodynamic equilibrium states of a system?  State what you do know about determining entropy change.

Comment: I know that $\Delta S = \int \frac{\delta Q}{T} + S_{gen}$

Comment: That's the way I would do it, and you already have an equation for $dQ$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to calculate the change in entropy of the water then its easy job.The process is not adiabatic as heat is supplied to the water and also it is reversible.So the change in entropy is simply $\Delta s=\int_{T_1}^{T_2}\frac{dQ}{T}=mc\ln (T_2/T_1)$.